# Using $timeout in ng-init to call a function to display shapes every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I'm attempting to use $timeout with Angular 1 to call a function every 2 seconds with ng-init.

```
ng-init="$timeout(sc.displaySorted(), 2000)"
```

The sc.displaySorted() is a function that displays 100 sorted shapes onto the DOM. That works on it's own on ng-init, but I haven't been able to figure out out to have it refresh every 2 seconds. I've also tried $route.reload and recursion.

Here is the vm.displaySorted function:

```
  vm.displaySorted = function() {
//calls generateFunc and pass total of 50 shapes
var allShapes = generateFunc(50);
//calls sortingFunc with argument of all shapes
var sortedShapes = sortingFunc(allShapes);
for(i = 0; i < sortedShapes.length; i++) {
  var shape = sortedShapes[i]
  if(shape.type === "square") {
    vm.shapesToDisplay.push(sortedShapes[i]);
  }
  if(shape.type === "circle") {
    vm.shapesToDisplay.push(sortedShapes[i]);
  }
}
```

};//end vm.displaySorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your are looking for is the [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service. You can use it like this:

```
$interval(displaySorted, 2000)
```

Notice here that

- I just put the function, and not the calling of it (no round brackets).
- You do not do in you view `ng-init="$interval(sc.displaySorted, 2000)"` because `$interval` is not available in the view but in the controller (a service injected by AngularJS), so you have to make a function wrapper of the function. See full sample below.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('myctrl', function($interval) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.wizard = {
      displaySorted: fnDisplaySorted,
      init: fnInit
    }

    return vm.wizard;

    function fnInit() {
      $interval(fnDisplaySorted, 2000);
    }

    function fnDisplaySorted() {
      console.log('printing');
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myctrl as ctrl" ng-init="ctrl.init()">
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be a function call: $interval(sc.displaySorted(), 2000)?

Comment: No, when you write it like that you are executing the function (intermediately, not what you want). You just have to put there the function, and the service will do the rest for you (execute it every X intervals, what you want! :) )

Comment: Hmmm, when I try that, it doesn't get called at all.

Comment: OK, I'll make a demo, give some time

Comment: @MattLarson, check the demo. I have noticed you were trying to  use `$timeout` in the view (you **cannot**, neither $interval), those are just available in the controller, since they are service injected by angular.

Comment: I've been trying it both ways. I copy/pasted your demo and added my code for displaySorted into the fnDisplaySorted function and the log is working, but not the code, with everything else exactly the same.

Comment: _and added my code_ .. you mean the code you posted in your question inside `vm.displaySorted`?

Comment: Yeah. the code I'm attempting to display on DOM every 2 seconds. It works on it's own, but inside the same function that is printing in the console every 2 seconds, it doesn't execute. The DOM stays blank, but the console prints every 2 seconds.

Comment: Please, could share with us a JSFiddle or a Plunkr, or anything similar?

Comment: Seems possible. I'm going to rest my eyes and come back to it in a bit. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

use `$interval` for this, you need to include it in the controller, refer the below example.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, $interval) {
  this.displaySorted = function() {
    console.log("every 2 seconds");
  }
  this.runThis = function(){
    $interval(this.displaySorted, 2000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController as sc' ng-app="myApp" ng-init="sc.runThis()">

</div>
```

Comment: Don't I have to set displaySorted() to the view model? I actually tried either way and it's not yet working.

Comment: @MattLarson Can you share the controller code? not everything, only the `displaySorted` function and the controller block. also is `sc` the `$scope` or `this`

Comment: @MattLarson Try this!

Comment: That is delaying the initial call for whatever the millisecond amount is set to, but it's not continuing to do it after the first call.

Comment: @MattLarson Try using this code, comment out all the lines, except add a `console.log()` inside the function `displaySorted()`, like what is seen in the example I gave! and verify the console is having the text added every 2 seconds, this will solve the `$interval` problem first!

Comment: @MattLarson Ok! so that solves your `$interval` problem, now verify the function works! by checking the output and also the console for any errors, then you can add back the commented lines!

Comment: Output definitely works. In combo with a few other functions, I am generating 50 squares and 50 circles with randomly generated side lengths and radiuses, sorted in descending order by area, onto the DOM. Perhaps it's a async issue?

Comment: @MattLarson I think the solution will be as you suggested using a `$timeout`, but there is a catch you need to recursively call the function. Also you need to use promises to make the function wait for it to finish before calling itself back, The simple fix will be to increase the `$interval` to a measured amount so that the function finishes before the interval restarts!

Comment: Ultimately I need to make the web page start a timer that regenerates and rerenders the shapes twice every second actually. I typed every 2 seconds earlier. Is there any possible way to do this with angular?

Comment: @MattLarson There will be a way using promises, can you share a fiddle with the issue? and also raise a new question with the exact issue and add this fiddle, you might get an answer to this!!! anyway this question is only for `$interval` so I hope you found your answer in either of the questions! if you feel your doubt is clarified for the question, kindly close it!